# How to render leaflet-maps in loops in RMDs with knitr

Tags: r, loops, leaflet, r-markdown, knitr

I am currently fighting trying to get knitr to render my leaflet maps, taken from a collection to appear correctly in a rendered RMD html-output. I'm already aware about some potential problems when looping throug collections and generating graphical output with RMD/knitr, but still I can't figure out, how to make my example work for leaflet-maps.

**Reproducible working example (Test_1.Rmd)**:

````
---
title: "test1"
author: "phabee"
date: "22 Mai 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Title 1

```{r, fig.show='asis', echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:4) {
    cat("### Plot Number ", i, "\n")
    plot(1,1)
    # use plot.new() here to force rendering of potential plot-duplicates
    plot.new()
    cat("\n\n")
}
```
````

The above example renders as expected (at least after adding plot.new(), which I've learned [here](https://github.com/r-lib/evaluate/issues/14) from *Freedomtowin*). But when I try to do the same with leaflet-maps, it doesn't work at all. No single map is being rendered:

**Reproducible failing example (Test_2.Rmd)**

````
---
title: "test2"
author: "phabee"
date: "22 Mai 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Title 1

```{r, fig.show='asis', echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:4) {
  cat("### Map Number ", i, "\n")
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")  
  cat("\n")
}
```
````

I would expect the second Rmd to render 4 times the same map, showing different titles ("Plot Number 1-4"). But the output doesn't render any map at all. The output looks as follows:

[image]

After inspecting the generated html-output the output, it can be seen that there is nothing rendered at all and it's not just a visibility-issue:

[image]

However, when I evaluate the leaflet-section within the 2nd Rmd directly by 'highlighting' the code and hitting ctrl-Enter, the map renders as expected:

[image]

I already tried to

- convert the leaflet-statement to an assignment statement
- introduce cat() or print() commands to force map-output
- play around with additional newline-characters '\n' before and/or after the map output section
- fiddle around with the 'asis' directives from *fig.show* or *results*

without any effect. Does anyone have a clue here?

Comment: I thought about a combination of `saveWidget(m, file = "./m.html")` and  `htmltools::includeHTML("./m.html")` but I can't make it work.

Comment: package `widgetframe` could possibly work..

Comment: using widgetframe did not work either and fiddling around with saving html seems no option; my current working but superugly workaround is adding explicit sections for the first n iterations to generate the map-output with concrete values of i.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put things in a tagList, and have that list print from the chunk.  This just uses default settings for `fig.show` and `results`; it also uses the `htmltools::h3()` function to turn the title into an HTML title directly, not using the Markdown `###` marker.  (You might want `h2` or `h4` instead.)

````
---
title: "test3"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Title 1

```{r echo=FALSE}
html <- list()
for (i in 1:4) {
  html <- c(html, 
            list(h3(paste0("Map Number ", i)),
                 leaflet() %>%
                 addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
                 addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")  
                 )
            )
}
tagList(html)
```
````

Comment: I have some similar problems. Perhaps you know, what's going on? See [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56989205/5784831), 
[Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56986638/5784831) and
[Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56983105/5784831). I am working on the Rmarkdown level (preferred).