# Can R's htmltools::includeHTML not handle leaflet maps?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown

I try to use the concept from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36524238/5784831) in an automated way, but maps are not displayed. The included html looks ok:

[image]

**Minimal reproducible example:** For the generation of the html see below or.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "SQC"
date: "11 Juli 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(leaflet)
save_path <- paste0("C:/Temp/SO-question/")
i <- 2
```

# Title level 1

This works

```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
htmltools::includeHTML(paste0(save_path, "helper_map_", i, ".html"))
```

But this does not

```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 2:3) {
  htmltools::includeHTML(paste0(save_path, "helper_map_", i, ".html"))
}
```
````

Where is the mistake? Any ideas?

---

**Reproducible example** with creation of maps

Create three files in "C:/Temp/SO-question" (then, everything will run without changes):

- render_hmtl.R
- report_include_html.Rmd
- helper_map_html.Rmd
- helper_table_html.Rmd

**The different files look like:**

**render_hmtl.R**

```
save_path <- paste0("C:/Temp/SO-question/")
load_path <- save_path
ranges <- paste0("section_", c(1:3))

cat("render html parts...\n")
for (i in 2:length(ranges)) {
  rmarkdown::render(paste0(load_path, 'helper_map_html.Rmd'), 
                    output_dir = save_path,
                    output_file = paste0("helper_map_", i, ".html"),
                    encoding = "UTF-8", quiet = T)
  rmarkdown::render(paste0(load_path, 'helper_table_html.Rmd'), 
                    output_dir = save_path,
                    output_file = paste0("helper_table_", i, ".html"),
                    encoding = "UTF-8", quiet = T)
}

cat("render html for comparison", paste(ranges, collapse = ", "), "...\n")
rmarkdown::render(paste0(load_path, 'report_include_html.Rmd'), 
                  output_dir = save_path,
                  output_file = "report_include_html.html",
                  encoding = "UTF-8", quiet = T)
```

**report_include_html.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "SQC"
date: "11 Juli 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(leaflet)
```

# Title level 1

This is an R Markdown document. 

## Title level 2 (tab) {.tabset}

### Title level 3 (tab) {.tabset}

```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 2:length(ranges)) {
  cat(paste0("#### Title level 4 `r ", 
             ranges[i], "` vs. `r ", ranges[i - 1], "` {.tabset}\n"))

  cat("##### Map\n")
  htmltools::includeHTML(paste0(save_path, "helper_map_", i, ".html"))

  cat("##### Tabelle\n")
  htmltools::includeHTML(paste0(save_path, "helper_table_", i, ".html"))
}
```

### Title level 3 (tab) {.tabset}

```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 2:length(ranges)) {
  cat(paste0("#### `r ", ranges[i], "` vs. `r ", ranges[i - 1], "` {.tabset}\n"))

  cat("##### Map\n")
  htmltools::includeHTML(paste0(save_path, "helper_map_", i, ".html"))

  cat("##### Tabelle\n")
  htmltools::includeHTML(paste0(save_path, "helper_table_", i, ".html"))
}
```
````

**helper_map_html.Rmd**

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7}
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Toner Lite")) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = 47, lng = 9, popup = ranges[i])
```
````

**helper_table_html.Rmd**

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
DT::datatable(data.frame(x = 1, y = ranges[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
              rownames = FALSE)
```
````

(This question originates from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56983105/5784831))